# Validation not working in pagination

Tags: javascript, checkbox, pagination

Here, I have multiple records with checkboxes.
Once I submit, it gives and error as I have created that "you have to select atlease one checkbox".
When I select on "select all" checkbox, It will select checkbox all page of checkbox in pagination.
But when I unchecked checkbox of particular page and others are checked, it also gives me an error to select checkbox when I submit.
So where I am going wrong in this checkbox validation with pagination?

My code:

```
$('#processorder').click(function() {
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

      if(!checked) {
        alert("Please select an Order(s)..!!");
        return false;
      }

    });

});

<div style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 10px;"><input type="submit" id="processorder" name="processorder" value="Process Order" class="submit-green"/></div>
```

Comment: Your code works ok. Looks like there is something wrong in other part of your app

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an extra check before the if-statment like this:

```js
$('#processorder').click(function() {
  checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0; //Extra check

  if(!checked) {
    alert("Please select an Order(s)..!!");
    return false;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Apples" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="Bananas" />

<div style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 10px;"><input type="submit" id="processorder" name="processorder" value="Process Order" class="submit-green"/></div>
```

Tyr out the snippet below, hope it helps!

/Zorken17

Comment: If you find this to be a good answer, please mark i as one. @Viral Bhoot

Answer (score -1):

As you can see you have an extra line that causes this error. Just remove it and it'll work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxvfn652/

```
$('#processorder').click(function() {
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

      if(!checked) {
        alert("Please select an Order(s)..!!");
        return false;
      }

    });

}); /*this line breaks your code. */
```

Comment: The code works with or without the blank line. How would this help the user?